# install Qt 5 addin for visual studio 2013

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2013, qt5

I have visual studio 2013, I installed Qt5 creator.
Now I can't install "qt-vs-addin-1.2.2-opensource"

it says

> the installer could not find an installation for visual studio 200x

Anyone know how to fix it ?

Comment: I have successfully installed the Add-in in VS2013 using this post: https://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/34769/P15

Answer (score 10):

For Qt5 add in link->

http://download.qt-project.org/official_releases/vsaddin/qt-vs-addin-1.2.3-opensource.exe

For Qt4 add in link->

http://download.qt-project.org/official_releases/vsaddin/qt-vs-addin-1.1.11-opensource.exe

Answer (score 2):

Okay, finally, they're doing it: https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTVSADDINBUG-172

Comment: Will be released in Qt 5.3, already available as Alpha: http://download.qt-project.org/development_releases/vsaddin/qt-vs-addin-opensource-1.2.3-alpha.exe

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record because I had some trouble with version `qt-vs-addin-1.2.3`, [qt-vs-addin-1.2.5](https://www1.qt.io/download-open-source/#section-7) worked for me.

Good luck.