# Qt Project System

Tags: c++, qt

So i've been learning Qt. I am currently working on a program that needs Qt and the first step is to create a Project System. Where you have like a project file and you can open it and it contains data. How do I make this type of system?

Comment: You mean qrc? if yes, take a look at this: [Qt5 Tutorial Resource Files](http://www.bogotobogo.com/Qt/Qt5_Resource_Files.php) and this [The Qt Resource System](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html)

Comment: No like inside the program you have a "New Project" that makes a project file that contains the projects data.

Comment: For QtCreator : [Basic Qt Programming Tutorial](https://wiki.qt.io/Basic_Qt_Programming_Tutorial). For Qt with VS you need to configure [qt add in](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21323118/install-qt-5-addin-for-visual-studio-2013) like this [Qt5 Tutorial Visual Studio Add-in](http://www.bogotobogo.com/Qt/Qt5_Visual_Studio_Add_in.php)